# How to apply style to an array of SVG elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have an array of `.svg` icons, where each icon has some properties which I need to override:

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> ... </svg>
```

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

import Github from 'assets/github.svg';
import Facebook from 'assets/facebook.svg';
import Twitter from 'assets/twitter.svg';
...

const icons = [
  <Github />,
  <Facebook />,
  <Twitter />,
  ...
];
```

I would like to apply the same styling for each icon **without duplicating code** and using `CSS-in-JS`.

My solution so far has some issues:

```
// Works but,
// I want to use CSS-in-JS like styled-components
// for easier maintenance
const iconStyle = {
  width: 50,
  height: 50
};

const SocialBar = () => (
  <IconBar as={FlexBox}>
    {icons.map((icon, key) => (
      <div key={key}>{React.cloneElement(icon, iconStyle)}</div>
    ))}
  </IconBar>
);
```

```js
// Works but,
// there are too many icons
const SocialBar = () => (
  <IconBar as={FlexBox}>
    <Github style={iconStyle} />
    <Facebook style={iconStyle} />
    ...
  </IconBar>
);
```

And styling `svg` component like this won't work:

```
// Won't override the width="24" height="24" properties
const StyledIcon = styled(Github)`
  width: 50;
  height: 50;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the SVG with an element (like an `i`) and style any `svg` children inside of it with some CSS defined within a styled-component (you can also target `g` and `path` as well). Unfortunately, SVGs are pretty tricky to work with, so you **may** need to manually copy/paste the SVG xml into a JS file (if you're using the [CRA](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started), you can import a [ReactComponent from an SVG](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-add-svgs-as-react-components-with-create-react-app-2-0)).

**Working example** (copy/pasted SVG into JS file -- 1st example is the default, 2nd example passes in props, 3rd example passes in multiple props):

[image: Edit Styled SVG Component]

---

**Icon/Icon.js** (this component accepts a styled component generated `className` and any `children` placed inside of it)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Icon = ({ className, children }) => (
  <i className={className}>{children}</i>
);

Icon.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default Icon;
```

**Icon/index.js** (this will style the `Icon` component above; and, subsequently it will style the `children`)

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import Icon from "./Icon";

const StyledIcon = styled(Icon)`
  margin: 0 20px;
  svg {
    fill: ${({ fill }) => fill || "#03a9f3"};
    height: ${({ dimension }) => dimension || "50px"};
    width: ${({ dimension }) => dimension || "50px"};
  }
`;

export default StyledIcon;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it.

```
//Github.js
import React from "react";
export default function Github({height, width}) {
    return (
        <svg width={width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 24 24"> ...  </svg>
    );
}
```

Then where you want to use it.

```
<Github height={24} width={24} />
```

Comment: How does it help? How I can apply it to icons array? It's like applying an inline style, this way I need to make a function for each icon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your request is, relative to the code samples you already have. Are you trying to avoid using `React.cloneElement`? Make the array of icons as functions, instead of a jsx element. `map` over it to the jsx version and apply the styles to each

```
const icons = [
  Github,
  Facebook,
  Twitter,
]

buildIcons() {
  const style = {
    //..
  }
  return icons.map((icon, idx) => (
    <icon style={style} key={idx}/>
  ))

}
```

Using index as the key works, but if you can find a different property that is unique to each icon, it'd be better.

Comment: I'm trying to style each icon using css-in-js, and btw your code won't work because `icon` need to be uppercased or react won't recognize it.

Comment: So like this? https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.22 It looks like jss has multiple HOCs that are available to you